# styling a <pre> tag

Tags: html, css, pre

In my website documentation, I have some code that should be displayed like to suggest the user how they can change the look and feel of the website by following the displayed code. I don't want to use the background image inside this `pre` tag but want some styling for it. like every line of code should have an alternate background color. I've linked the inspiration image.

[image: demo image]

```css
  pre {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 450px;
  border-left: 12px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
.header-inner {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: Fix the line-height to a specific number of pixels, then  create a repeating-linear-gradient for the background.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @Mr Lister said, use gradients.

```css
.my-pre{
  line-height:1.2em;
  background:linear-gradient(180deg,#ccc 0,#ccc 1.2em,#eee 0);
  background-size:2.4em 2.4em;
  background-origin:content-box;
  
  /* some extra styles*/
  padding:0 20px;
  text-align:justify;
  font-family:calibri,arial,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre class="my-pre">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Voluptate ab pariatur assumenda ipsum exercitationem tempore
  architecto, adipisci, id nihil culpa molestias rerum, dolore alias?
  Fugit eos doloribus dolore, expedita officiis.
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

As the comments above have mentioned, you will have to use a linear gradient. Since you actually have a top and bottom padding declared (which, when different from your line-height, will interfere with the relative offset of text against the gradient), you will have to set the y position of the background-image:

```
background-position: 0 14px;
```

...assuming that your top-padding is 14px (as stated in your example).

## Solution 1: Using `linear-gradient`

[`linear-gradient` is actually very widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) among modern browsers today (>93% unprefixed, >94% prefixed). For `linear-gradient`, the start and end color stops are assumed to be the same as the closest breakpoint, so all you need to declare is:

1. Two breakpoints, color A and color B both at 50% (middle)
2. Set your background height to 2× the line-height

i.e.:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #eee 50%, #fff 50%);
background-size: 100% 48px;
```

```css
pre {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 450px;
  border-left: 12px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 14px;
  
  /* Fixed line height */
  line-height: 24px;
  
  /* Use linear-gradient for background image */
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #eee 50%, #fff 50%);
  
  /* Size background so that the height is 2x line-height */
  background-size: 100% 48px;
  
  /* Offset the background along the y-axis by top padding */
  background-position: 0 14px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
.header-inner {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}
</pre>
```

## Solution 2: Using `repeating-linear-gradient`

Using [`repeating-linear-gradient`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients) is very similar to `linear-gradient`, but remember to declare all color stops (the start and end stops are not assumed):

1. color A at 0px (start)
2. color A at 24px (1× line-height)
3. color B at 24px (1× line-height)
4. color B at 48px (2× line-height)

i.e.:

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    #eee 0px,
    #eee 24px,
    #fff 24px,
    #fff 48px);
```

Here is an example:

```css
pre {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 450px;
  border-left: 12px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 14px;
  
  /* Fixed line height */
  line-height: 24px;
  
  /* Use repeating-linear-gradient for background image */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      #eee 0px,
      #eee 24px,
      #fff 24px,
      #fff 48px);

  /* Offset the background along the y-axis by top padding */
  background-position: 0 14px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
.header-inner {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned by other you can use `linear gradiant`

```css
pre {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 450px;
  border-left: 12px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  padding: 0em 1em;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<pre>
.header-inner {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}
</pre>
```

Simple approach,

```js
$("pre").html(function (index, html) {
    return html.replace(/^(.*)$/mg, "<span class=\"line\">$1</span>")
});
```

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: line-numbering;
  background: #2c3e50;
  padding: 12px 0px 14px 0;
  width: 600px;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 100%;
}

pre .line::before {
  content: counter(line-numbering);
  counter-increment: line-numbering;
  padding-right: 1em;
  /* space after numbers */
  padding-left: 8px;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
.header-inner {
width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}
</pre>
```

With line numbers,

```js
$("pre").html(function(index, html) {
  return html.replace(/^(.*)$/mg, "<span class=\"line\">$1</span>")
});
```

```css
pre {
  counter-reset: line-numbering;
  background: #2c3e50;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 450px;
  border-left: 12px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 14px;
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(top, #444 0px, #444 22px, #2f2f2f 22px, #2f2f2f 44px);
  padding: 0em 1em;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

pre .line::before {
  content: counter(line-numbering);
  counter-increment: line-numbering;
  padding-right: 1em;
  /* space after numbers */
  padding-left: 8px;
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
.header-inner {
 width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: 'lato', sans-serif;
}
</pre>
```

Comment: `#2f2f2f` is so dark you can't see the text... Try *Run code snippet*.